# Prove that $n^2$ is $O(3^n)$ (Big OH)

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I just started learning algorithms and I have started doing some exercises. I am asked to prove $O(3^n)$ (The O is the Big OH notation). How can I prove this, I looked at the definition of Big O, but I am still not sure.

Comment: Did you try using log

Comment: Not sure about what? The definition of $O(3^n)$? It is trivial that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n^2}{3^n}=0$, hence $n^2 = o(3^n)$.

Comment: Maybe give the definition of Big $O$ you are looking at, that might help.

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio, I might be dumb, but can you explain how n^2/3^n equals 0?

Comment: No, I don't think so, you just don't seem to be familiar with the notion of "limit". Fortunately, you don't need it for "big oh" (for "small oh", you do). @Jack D'Aurizio didn't say $n^2/3^n$ equals $0$, but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^2/3^n$ _is_ $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigO notation represents a set. The set O(3^n) contains all functions that are asymtotically smaller than or equaivalent to 3^n. You need to consider the definition of BigO first.

f(x) is in O(g(x)), if f(x)<=k*g(x), where k is a constant and x is sufficiently big (for every x such that x>y for some y). An easy approach is to take the limit of x as it approaches to infinity. This makes sense because the definition of limit in infinity is also something like for every x such that x>y for some y. But since you are newly learning these, better stick to the explicit definition with for every x such that x>y for some y.

Back to your question:
Your task is to find some y and k such that for every x that is bigger than y, x^2 is smaller than k*(3^x). k=1 and y=1 is a valid solution, because for every x that is bigger than 1, x^2 is smaller than 3^x. But we need to prove this right, even though it is obvious. Use induction:

```
x^2 < 3^x
x is bigger than 1, but lets assume 1 is also the base case since it is also correct for the equation above.

1^2 < 3^1
1 < 3

Now assume it is correct for x=k

k^2 < 3^k

Check x = k+1

(k+1)^2 < 3^(k+1)
k^2 + 2k + 1 < 3*3^k
We know that k^2 >= 2k > 1 for k>1 which k+1>2. We need it to be correct for k+1=2 as well because for k=1 as the base case k+1's requirement starts from 2, so I will check it seperately.
2^2 < 3^2 --> It holds. Back to k^2 + 2k + 1 < 3*3^k.
We now know k^2 >= 2k > 1 for k+1 = 3, 4 ... That's why:
k^2 + 2k + 1 < 3*(k^2)
We assumed k^2 < 3^k, it yields 3*(k^2) < 3*(3^k). So,
k^2 + 2k + 1 < 3*(k^2) < 3*(3^k)
k^2 + 2k + 1 < 3*(3^k)
(k+1)^2 < 3^(k+1). So here it is proven.
```

Short summary, x=1 is the base case and checked, x=k is assumed, x=k+1 had an exception in my method for k=1, so I checked it manually and proved the x=k+1 for every k>1. So I covered all x that is bigger than or equal to 1 which ended the proof.

Thus, x^2 belongs to O(3^x).

Answer (score 0):

Remember: $f(n)=O(g(n))$ means there is a constant $C$ so that $|f(n)|\le C\,|g(n)|$ for all $n$. But $n^2\le C\,3^n$ means $n^2/3^n\le C$, i.e. the LHS must be bounded. That's easy to see in this case: the quotient of consecutive terms is $(1+1/n)^2/3$, and that's $<1$ if and only if $n\ge2$. So the maximum is attained for $n=2$, meaning $C=4/9$ will do.